# Java Socket Exception (Null) on Android app. At my wits end

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

First of hello everyone,

The situation:
I have started writing (part of) a program that that should send (in this stage) send a simple message "Hello World!" from a android (client) to a C# server (on my computer).
Both devices are connected over the wifi.

Simple testing:
I have made sendTCP(); in Java on my computer, and tested it it with the c# server and it works perfectly. So I just copied it into my android code. and added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to the manifest.

The problem:
Once I run it on my phone (Also tried on the emulator same problem). Once I click the button, a exception gets thrown with the exception.getMessage() == null....
So my TextView changes to: ***asfdasnull*** weirdly enough it is just null, not nullpointerexception.

Can anyone help me? or hint me in the right direction?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button myButton;
    TextView label;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                wtf("dsgfdsg1");
                try{
                sendTCP();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    wtf("asfdas"+ex.getMessage());
                    //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void sendTCP() throws Exception{

        String s = "Hello World!";
        byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
        msg = s.getBytes();

        Socket so = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 5004);
        OutputStream outstream = so.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream datastream = new DataOutputStream(outstream);
        datastream.write(msg, 0, s.length());

        datastream.close();
        outstream.close();
        so.close();
    }

    public void wtf(String s){
        label.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: An exception doesn't need to have a message. You'd get more information by printing the stack trace.

Comment: Not 100% sure this is the error but you should not do any network operations on the main (UI) thread or you will get this exception: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: What exception is being thrown if its not NPE?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadExeption`. Put the sendTCP() call in an AsyncTask or thread.

Answer (score 0):

thx for the quick answer. I totaly forgot that I need to get getStackTrace() and not get Message().

So basically I had to toss the sendTCP() into a thread and worked like a charm!

Thank you all.